# Firebase custom auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm kinda new guy with firebase, and my question is - is there any way to add custom authentication, i.e. , for example with some form of id and password instead of proposed methods?

Comment: oh, yea, sorry. It's helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build whatever you want with Firebase [custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Signing in with a username + password has been covered quite a few times already, so I recommend checking out some of those [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+username+password) and this [example of implementing this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/username-password-auth).